# What is the Channel ID in 1ML.com?

Tags: lightning-network, channels

To look up information of a channel on [1ML.com](https://1ML.com), I wonder how the `channel_id` is built.

Reading [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84795/how-to-obtain-the-channel-id-from-the-short-channel-id) and the [corresponding BOLT02](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#the-funding_signed-message), I see that

```
channel_id = funding_txid XOR funding_output_index
```

As the `funding_txid` is a 32 byte string (e.g. `399986f8d47b36d4f21c07de0ce7d422de244ed58a72e6b44d26985fe1e7465c`), the `channel_id` has also 32 bytes.

However, when looking at a [specific channel at 1ML.com](https://1ml.com/channel/617430754733195265), the `channel_id` is much shorter (e.g., `735416048958177281`).

Hence my question is:

- Is the above definition of the `channel_id` correct? If so, what is the difference to the one of 1ML.com?
- Otherwise: How is the `channel_id` computed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `channel_id` in 1ml seems to be the lnd encoding of the `short_channel_id`. Note that the short Channel ID is just 3 bytes of blockheight, 3 bytes of transaction index within the and 2 bytes for the output index within the transaction. While BOLTs recommend to serialize this as HEIGHTxINDEXxOUTPUT lnd just concatenated those 8 bytes and displays them as a single large integer. I guess since lightning explorer tend to take over the APIs of implementations we have this confusion

Comment: More details on how to convert between lnd and say c-lightning short channel ID: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78029/how-to-convert-channel-id-from-c-lightning-to-lnd

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. Indeed, 1ML.com uses the "LND sid format".